# How to break a long list sentence into multiple lines in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am building a personal website and pretty new to html. My navbar looks like

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Bob Mandal | Projects</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="MyWebsiteScript.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyStyleSheet.css" />
</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse  navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container-fluid">
      <!---logo-->
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
          <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
          <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
          <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
        </button>
        <a class="navbar-brand" style="font-weight: bold">Bob Mandal</a>
      </div>

      <!--menu Item here-->
      <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li>
            <a href="#" style="font-weight: bold">About Me</a>
          </li>
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="font-weight: bold">Curriculum Vitae<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
              <li>
                <a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold">CV</a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" target="_blank" style="font-weight: bold">Resume</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li class="active dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" style="font-weight: bold">Projects<span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu project-menu">
              <li style="text-align: center">
                <a href="#Pilot" style="font-weight: bold" class="sidebarlink">Research</a>
              </li>
              <li style="text-align: center">
                <a href="#PIRAT" style="font-weight: bold">Arrrgh</a>
              </li>
              <li style="text-align: center">
                <a href="#SAMPLE" style="font-weight: bold">This is a very long sentence which I need to divide into two line.Is it possible?</a>
              </li>
              <li style="text-align: center">
                <a href="#Quad" style="font-weight: bold">Quad</a>
              </li>
            </ul>
          </li>
        </ul>

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
          <li>
            <a href="#" style="font-weight: bold">Contact</a>
          </li>
          <li id="linkedIn">
            <a href="#" width="22px" />Linked in</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>
```

My first question to all the experts, how do I wrap the long sentence in my drop down menu in multiple sentences? I am not worries about big screens but on a standard android phone it looks ghastly.

My second question is on mobile devices when the navbar is  a dropdown like menu. How to ensure the navbar retracts or closes or collapses after user clicks a menu item. Right now I have to toggle the icon on the top right of the screen to retract or collapse the dropdown menu.

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score -1):

You can very easily do this by adding the second line in-between paragraph tags.
like so: http://jsfiddle.net/ycUB6/10706/

```
  <a href="#SAMPLE" style="font-weight: bold">This is a very long sentence which
  <p>I need to divide into two line.Is it possible</p></a>
```